# Android In app Billing Package name conflict

Tags: android, in-app-billing, aidl

I am trying to integrate InApp billing AIDL interface (where package name starts with "com."), to my project (where package name starts with "mywork."). So AIDL now tries to auto generate java files(in gen folder) under "com", which is not available in my case as my package name is different. So the build error.

Plz Help.

Comment: Create android folder inside com folder and vending,billing folders in hierarchy where your actual source resides in the drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by creating android library project with package name starting from "com" and moved market billing AIDL into that.

Answer (score 0):

Add your AIDL interface file in the com.android.vending.billing package under the src folder in your application.

Comment: Using the same approach.It can not be built.Under src I have one folder named "mywork"(my project) and another one is "com"(billing package), which will not work out. It can only be built if a place my project and billing package under src/com

Comment: Rename your project package by com.mywork under src folder and add  com.android.vending.billing package under the src folder in your application.Clean your project than.

Comment: Thanks for reply..My problem is, if I change the package name new build can not act as upgrade build for the existing ones

Comment: Create a new project and add your project package and com.android.vending.billing package into the project.Clean and Build and when to upload the apk make sure the package name does not change becuase apps are identified through their package names and not by their app names.

Comment: If package name is changed that will be installed as a separate application, it will nor replace the existing one. Solved my problem by creating android library project and later linking that to my main project